# openvpn exits with error 1194 port already in use

Tags: raspbian-stretch, vpn, systemd, services

I have pivpn installed on my raspbian stretch running on 1194 port.

in the beginning it was working fine , but now from few days I am getting this error on reboot.

```
Sep 26 21:17:29 titan ovpn-bridge-clt[7641]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]10.10.10.10:1194
Sep 26 21:17:29 titan systemd-timesyncd[318]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Sep 26 21:17:29 titan ovpn-bridge-clt[7641]: TCP/UDP: Socket bind failed on local address [AF_INET][undef]:1194: Address already in use
Sep 26 21:17:29 titan systemd-timesyncd[318]: Synchronized to time server 178.62.16.103:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Sep 26 21:17:29 titan ovpn-bridge-clt[7641]: Exiting due to fatal error
Sep 26 21:17:29 titan systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to bridge-clt.
-- Subject: Unit openvpn@bridge-clt.service has failed
```

I googled the error and found few hints:

and I think [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/516016/comments/5) is the possible fix tp problem , maybe the openvpn starts too early.

But I am not expert to understand the `/etc/init.d/openvpn`  because there are so many places where start_vpn appears.

I have also tried all the possible solutions here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=178161

but no success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The link *this* you have given, recommending to use a `sleep` may have been a solution in 2010 but nowadays **systemd** is used. `/etc/init.d/` is deprecated and only emulated by systemd for backward compatibility. You should not look at it anymore. Look at systemd.

Comment: Get the output from ```sudo netstat -tlnpu | grep 1194``` that should tell you what process is using port 1194.

Comment: On my default **pivpn** setup there is no `ovpn-bridge-clt` used. What do you do to use it? How do you enable/configure it? For what do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message `Address already in use` means that there is already another process that has bound that address to a socket. Most of the time it is another instance of the same program, in this case another `openvpn` process.

Use `sudo ss -ntuap | grep :1194` to find processes using port 1194.

If the address `10.10.10.10` from the first line of the output is the address of your server, it is possible that the process interferes with itself. There are rules about binding the same port to a specific address and to the wildcard address.